# dropbox.js, successful sign-in code not executed

Tags: javascript, oauth, dropbox

So I'm playing around with dropbox.js. In the Getting Started guide on github the code snippet for signing in is:

```
client.authenticate(function(error, client) {
  if (error) {
    // Replace with a call to your own error-handling code.
    //
    // Don't forget to return from the callback, so you don't execute the code
    // that assumes everything went well.
    return showError(error);
  }

  // Replace with a call to your own application code.
  //
  // The user authorized your app, and everything went well.
  // client is a Dropbox.Client instance that you can use to make API calls.
  doSomethingCool(client);
});
```

Background:I'm using the Dropbox.Drivers.Redirect driver, so upon calling client.authenticate() the user gets whisked away to the Dropbox signin page, signs in, authorizes my app, and is then redirected back to the page the whole process started from.

However my doSomethingCool() method (or indeed, any part of the callback passed to authenticate()) is totally ignored after signing in to Dropbox and the redirect back to my page.

However, if the user is *already* signed in to Dropbox when authenticate() is called, dropbox.js does not whisk them away to dropbox.com (I guess it just internally verifies that the current session is valid), but the callback (and doSomethingCool()) does get executed!

The actual thing I want to do is this: on my page, the user is selecting a method of backing storage for a webapp. Once they sign in to Dropbox and they're redirected back to my page, I actually want them to go to the main part of the app, not this little selector screen. There doesn't appear to be a method to specify a different return address after the dropbox sign in, so I was going to do it manually using window.location.replace in authenticate()'s callback. But it doesn't work  :(

One alternative would be to send a flag to my domain using AJAX, before calling client.authenticate() - to indicate a user is in the OAuth flow. Then when my selector screen gets requested again from my server (via the redirect after the dropbox sign in), do an auto redirect to the main app. But it's a bit messy (no?)